# What is involved in getting RefTagger or an equivalent on bh.se?

Tags: feature-request

Reftagger locates scripture references on your page and when you hover over them it shows the text.

http://blog.biblia.com/2014/04/add-trouble-free-scripture-to-your-site-with-reftagger/

Comment: Oh. Most probably a special pleading on MetaSE, appealing to the site devs. –– As practical as that might be, for one, beta, site that seems *very* unlikely to come true…

Comment: More realistically might be to look for a userscript solution?

Comment: I'm considering trying to implement it with Google Scripts but that requires being installed.